# Clear managed_file field on submit

Tags: 7, forms, files

I'd like to clear the managed file field each time the contents are sent off for further processing on submit.

The callbacks work fine, but I have repeatedly come unstuck in my goal of having a "fresh" form everytime I need to submit a new image.

The form is defined thus:

```
function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state) {

$form['Input type'] = array(
    '#type'=>'fieldset',
    '#title'=>'Upload your image'
);

$form['Input type']['file'] = array(
    //file left in non-permanent state for testing purposes
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title'=> t('Upload image'),
    '#description' => t('Choose an image to upload. Format must be gif, png, jpg, and may not exceed 2MB in size. Press Submit to confirm your selection.'),
    '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' > array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
        'file_validate_size'=>array(512*512*512),
    ),
    '#upload_location'=>'public://mymodule_uploads',
);

$form['Input type']['submit'] = array(
    '#type'=>'submit',
    '#value' =>t('Submit'),
    '#submit'=>array('mymodule_clear_image_submit'),
    '#ajax' => array(
            'callback'=> 'mymodule_update_image_callback',
            'wrapper'=>'somediv'
        ),
);
return $form;
}
function mymodule_update_image_callback($form,&$form_state) {
$picture_settings = array( 
        'image' => file_create_url($form['Input type']['file']['#file']->uri)
        );
    drupal_add_js(array('mymodule' => $picture_settings),'setting');

    return;
}

function mymodule_clear_image_submit($form,&$form_state) {
$form_state['complete form']['Input type']['file']['#file'] = NULL;
$form_state['rebuild']=TRUE;
return;
}
```

Neither the submit nor the callback functions seems to be refreshing my form. Setting the file value to NULL has not had an effect either.

I don't know what else to try. Cheers!

Comment: Try removing 'file' from `$form_state['input']` and `$form_state['values']`

Comment: That does seem to remove the file, but it doesn't update the form. I need the `managed_file` field to be empty after submitting.

Comment: Sorry I'm not getting you - unless the field has a #default_value, it will be empty next time the page is loaded

Comment: Sorry, what I am looking for is a way to refresh the form using ajax (ie that the field is emptied without having to reload the entire page)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1578656

The idea is to add the following keys to the 'file_managed' field at the time you want to clear it:

```
$form[FORMKEY]['#file'] = FALSE;
$form[FORMKEY]['filename'] = array();
$form[FORMKEY]['#value']['fid'] = 0;
```

In your case it should be something like this in the form builder function:

```
if ( isset($form_state['storage']['reset-file-field'])
  && $form_state['storage']['reset-file-field'] === true
) {
  $form['Input type']['file']['#file'] = FALSE;
  $form['Input type']['file']['filename'] = array();
  $form['Input type']['file']['#value']['fid'] = 0;

  $form_state['storage']['reset-file-field'] = false;
}
```

And then in your submit handler:

```
$form_state['storage']['reset-file-field'] = true;
```

The if-block is necessary to prevent the upload field being reset when you press 'upload', thus making it useless.

Comment: It worked form me. Thanx

Comment: @Clemorphy That is such a perfect typo :) And glad I could help here almost 5 years later.

Comment: Haha I just discover my typo. My subconscious made me use this word ;-)